# How to prove that $\cos(n\theta) \geq 0 \forall n \implies \theta=0?$

Tags: trigonometry

How to prove that $\cos(n\theta) \geq 0 \ \forall \ n$ implies $\theta=0$?

Does $\cos(n\theta) \geq 0 \ \forall \ n$ \imply $-\pi/2 \leq n\theta \leq \pi/2$ for all $n$?

Comment: How about $\theta=2\pi$?

Comment: Or $\theta$ = $\Pi$ where n=3?

Comment: What do you guys mean?

Comment: We mean it ain't true,Anonymous. We just gave you 2 different counterexamples.

Comment: I have a feeling the question should either have $\theta$ restricted, like $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$, or some kind of conclusion like $\theta \equiv 0\ \mod 2\pi$ instead. But of course it *didn't* say this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all, no, it does not imply $-\pi/2 \leq n\theta \leq \pi/2$ since at n = 3, where $\theta$ = $\Pi$, cos ($n\theta$) = -1. You can't prove something that has a counterexample.

The interesting question now-how do you alter the claim so that it **is** true?

Comment: I got it. How can I prove that if $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ is such that $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$, and $\cos(n\theta) \geq 0$ for every positive integer $n,$ then $\theta = 0?$